# What base serializer does protobuf-net use to output byte array?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Does protobuf-net use BinaryFormatter or other formatter as an base serializer to serialize an object as byte[], and then write to stream?

add:

I use protobuf-net serialize data and want to deserialize in golang, is there any serializer can do the work in go?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is a from-scratch serializer that does its own writing.  The source is available for you to examine.  Were it otherwise, it could only be slower than `BinaryFormatter` for instance and would suffer from the same limitations.  Instead it is faster and has its own minor limitations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protobuf-net is a ground-up implementation of the "Protocol Buffers" serialization format, with an idiomatic .NET API. It has nothing to do with `BinaryFormatter` (although it can be *used* to create custom `ISerializable` implementations for use *with* `BinaryFormatter`, if you still play in that world).

If you want to use Protocol Buffers (protobuf) with Go, just pick one of the Go implementations from [this list](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/docs/third_party.md).

Most protobuf libraries are "contract first", meaning: you need a .proto schema; to get that from protobuf-net, use `Serializer.GetProto<T>()` for the `T` that you are using as a root type.

Note: if you are serializing `DateTime` or `TimeSpan`, it would be a good idea to make sure that you are using `DataFormat.WellKnown` on those members - it'll make it *much* easier to work in a cross-platform way with other libraries; but note that this is *not* a data-compatible change: it fundamentally changes how those values are stored, so : if you have existing data you'll need to think of a migration strategy.

Comment: BTW, does profobuf-net support generates C# code with a given .proto file? the google tools makes the code complicated.

Comment: @JeffreyHill yes; simplest way is https://protogen.marcgravell.com, but the same tools are available as standalone command-line tools, MSBuild plugins, or a .NET "global tool"